# How to write an event trigger which send alerts to a JMS Queue

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, event-triggers

Is there any example where, we can trigger an event to send messages to JMS Queue when a table is updated/inserted ect for MYSQL/Postgre?

Comment: Have you tried NOTIFY? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-notify.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a good task for pg_message_queue (which you can get off Google Code or PGXN), which allows you to queue requests.  pg_message_queue doesn't do a great job of parallelism yet (in terms of parallel queue consumers), but I don't think you need that.

What you really want to do (and what pg_message_queue provides) is a queue table to hold the jms message, and then a trigger to queue that message.  Then the question is how you get it from there to jms.  You have basically two options (both of which are supported):

1. LISTEN for notifications, and when those come in handle them.
2. Periodically poll for notifications.  You might do this if you have a lot of notifications coming in, so you can batch them every minute or so, or if you have few notifications coming in and you want to process them at midnight.

Naturally that is PostgreSQL only.  Doing the same on MySQL?  I don't know how to do that.  I think you would be stuck with polling the table, but you could use pg_message_queue to understand basically how to do the rest.  Note that in all cases this is fully transactional so the message would not be sent until after transaction commit, which is probably what you want.